# Required enum for ViewModel possible in dotnet core?

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public MyEnum MyEnum { get; set; }
}

public enum MyEnum
{
    First,
    Second
}
```

Then in my view ..

```
<form action="/Go/Here" method="post">
    <select asp-for="MyEnum" asp-items="Html.GetEnumSelectList<MyEnum>()">
    <option selected="selected" value="">Please Select..</option>
    </select>
<button type="submit" value="Submit">Submit</button>
```

I am trying to have a generated enum form that requires a selection without defaulting to the first value.  However, currently they are able to submit while `Please Select..` is selected and dotnet will think `MyEnum.First` is selected.  Is it possible to do this without adding a Default Enum value and checking that the default enum value is not selected? Because that seems very hacky.

Comment: **dotnet will think MyEnum.First is selected.** ? how do you know that ? I tried your code and it gives me a validation error message and `ModelState.IsValid` is `false`

Comment: @Shyju Well 1) It always returns invalid state for some reason (for the example code). 2) I print out `MyViewModel.MyEnum` and when `Please Select..` is submitted, it prints out `First` when `First` is selected it prints out `First` and when `Second` is selected, it prints out `Second`.

Comment: Nevermind, I figured out the issue.  You were right, the code is working fine! Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Behind the scene, Enums are numbers. When you render your page, you will see that the option "First" is selected instead of "Please select..". This is because the option with text "First" has the value `0` and 0 is the default value for `int` type. So when the form is submitted with "Please select" as the option, the form data item for "MyEnum" will be empty/null, but since the type is non nullable type, model binder will set the first enum option.

You should change your type to nullable enum.

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public MyEnum? MyEnum { get; set; }
}
```

Now when user selects "Please select" and submit the form, the value will be `NULL` instead of the first enum(0)